# Format Date based on Browser time zone (VueJs/JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a Date in string Format: 2020-07-13 7:07 AM (which is indian time). I need to change this time based on browser time zone which can be either in US or Africa.

I have tried following ways, but i am not able to convert it correctly.
Attaching my steps:

```
var d = "2020-07-13 7:07 AM";
var date = new Date(d); //Mon Jul 13 2020 07:07:00 GMT+0530 (India StandardTime)
var date1 = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm T'); //undefined
```

Please help me out. I havee to this in both VueJs and Javascript

Comment: You need to include the timezone in your date string somehow, otherwise there's no way to localise it in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your timestamps to an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format including the UTC-offset. This can be done for instance using `new Date().toISOString()`. Then you can feed the timestamp into `moment` or, if you want to display the time for a different timezone, have a look at [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: I got date in 2020-07-13T01:37:00.000Z format. I have to take timezone based on browser time. Is it possible. I tried Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone, is it correct way to use in all browser?

Comment: To display timedata in the users own timezone, you can directly use `moment` in combination with the UTC-timestamp. However, if you want to store the users timezone or display the time for a different timezone, then you can grab the browsers timezone using `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`. All modern browsers support this option.

Comment: I have tried this, but getting wrong one:var jun = moment(dec);var t = jun.format(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone); I am getting output as AM0iam/Cam7/13/2020cuttam

Comment: You cannot put the timezone into the `format`-function of `moment`. `format()` is purely for "how should the timestamp look like". To explicitly set the timezone for a timestamp you have to use an additional library like `moment-timezone`

Comment: I have given in this format, but getting error: var dec = moment("2020-07-13T01:37:00.000Z");var tt = moment.tz(dec, "Asia/Calcutta"); Whats wrong in this?? Showing error as moment-timezone.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rule' of undefined
    at h.zoneAndRule (moment-timezone.js:1)
    at h.offset (moment-timezone.js:1)
    at Function.t.updateOffset (moment-timezone.js:1)

Comment: How can i get correct date time format from this: 2020-07-13T01:37:00.000Z

Comment: The correct usage according to the [docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) is `var jun = moment("2020-07-13T01:37:00.000Z"); jun.tz('Asia/Calcutta').format('ha z')`. Make sure, you have the correct arguments for each function. `moment.tz(dec, "Asia/Calcutta")` is for converting time data to another timezone

Comment: while using this:  jun.tz('Asia/Calcutta').format('ha z') getting an error rule not defined

Comment: Then you probably did not add the timezone data. You can do that using `moment.tz.add("Asia/Kolkata|Asia/Calcutta")`. In the error message should be a link included to the corresponding [docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/) page

Comment: I have used this way: moment.tz(jun, (_app.timeZone || "Asia/Kolkata")).format(_app.momemntWithShortTime);I am getting DateTime as 7/13/2020 1:06 AM. But instead of AM i need PM. Here _app.timeZone = "America/Indiana/Indianapolis" and  _app.momemntWithShortTime = M/D/YYYY h:mm A

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the answer in this way:

```
    var buildDate = "2020-07-13_7:07";
    let releaseDate = buildDate .split('_');
    let date = moment(date);
    let newDate = moment(new Date(date.get('year'), date.get('month'), date.get('date'), date.get('hour'), date.get('minute'))).add(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*-1, 'm').toDate();
let result = moment(newDate).format('MMM DD YYYY h:mm A');
```